# Flask: "Autodetected change in: path/to/file, reloading" displayed multiple times

Tags: python, flask

I recently noticed that when I edit a file while flask is on debug mode and watchdog is installed, the server prints

```
 * Detected change in '/path/to/file.py', reloading      
 * Detected change in '/path/to/file.py', reloading      
 * Detected change in '/path/to/file.py', reloading
```

That is, it prints the same message three times. This however doesn't happen when flask uses "stat" instead - in that case the message is only displayed once.

Why does this happen, and why does this only happen with watchdog?

Comment: You ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope, never resolved it.